# How can I convert string to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my string.

```
[('hxe718a186f56f9330368d69a6f47b459427a16a17', 3), ('hx08737510fbd9eaa5182354eb826a8ce84f659ab1', 1), ('hx579250b23b1bcc809da119182bc0b8421922701f', 7), ('hx0deffb4c44da662a9b36008a5ccd3e2ef704e803', 3)]
```

I want to convert this string to array or JSON.

var arr = `"Some works that covert string to array or JSON"`

So I want to get the result like bottom.

arr[0] = > ('hxe718a186f56f9330368d69a6f47b459427a16a17', 3)

arr[1] = > ('hx08737510fbd9eaa5182354eb826a8ce84f659ab1', 1)
...

Is there any way to do this? I can't find the way.

Comment: You'll want to do a couple artfully crafted passes of the `.split` function. It doesn't look like you've tried yet, so that should get you started.

Comment: Please give more insights to your question you want to encrypt and store in array or convert a string to array. To convert string to array use `string.split('')`

Comment: if you replace `(` with `[` and replace `)` with `]` and replace `'` with `"` then you can just JSON.parse it as an array of arrays.

Comment: Issue is if that is wha you have, it is not valid JSON with the ( and )

Comment: @window.document i very much doubt that.

Comment: Yea because of the format of the string. Else the OP can use that to parse to json @TKoL

Comment: Hi 김영주, welcome to Stack Overflow. What you're asking is actually quite straightforward (see @TKoL's comment) - but we can't help you unless you can show us what you have already attempted, and why it isn't working for you. Check out Stack Overflow's guidance on how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @window.document Your comment is, "If the string he's trying to parse was different, he'd be able to use JSON.parse". But the string he's trying to parse ISN'T different, so he can't use that.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Actually, I have done some of above answer.
However I'm a beginner ,so I didn't get the result that I want.
First time I wrote the process that I did and then I removed it.
Because I can't speak English well, so I think it gives confusion to people.
It was my mistake. 
Next time, I will try to do my best to question. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex - Doing a match for brackets `()` with `/\((.*?)\)/g` would be sufficient in your case.

The following snippet shows data as you expect:

```js
const string = "[('hxe718a186f56f9330368d69a6f47b459427a16a17', 3), ('hx08737510fbd9eaa5182354eb826a8ce84f659ab1', 1), ('hx579250b23b1bcc809da119182bc0b8421922701f', 7), ('hx0deffb4c44da662a9b36008a5ccd3e2ef704e803', 3)]";
const arr = string.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is the result that I want!

Comment: If this is helpful, would you mind accepting the answer please :) Thank you :)